# Arduino mills() overflow

Tags: arduino-uno

I have motor programmed with arduino, the hardware is already setup so i don't want to change the micro controller. I need to give the motor 1 second to move from each point to the other and if its too much stay until "one second" is done and then go the rest of the code.
 the bellow code this is part of the whole code. it freezes and not working after about 40 hour. please advise how can i prevent that. I know that the mills() function is the problem but don't know whats the best option to replace or prevent that?

```
    unsigned long firsttime = 0;
    unsigned long secondtime = 0;


    void loop(){
        ...
        firsttime= millis();
        myStepper.step(RNum);
        secondtime = 1000-millis()+firsttime;
        delay (secondtime);
        ...
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: millis() should rollover after 49 days, not 40 hours. Have you looked here : https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/how-can-i-handle-the-millis-rollover

Comment: Thanks for the link, I read that before I ask a question but that couldn't solve my problem. In my case, it doesn't take that long to freez. Also, as I'm comparing time duration, shouldn't it just not rollover? what should I do to be able to run non stop?